# getting started with django-cms: error on page_submit_row

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am getting started with django-cms and I am facing an exception when I try to edit a page in the admin inteface.

A `TemplateSyntaxError` exception is raised due to the `{% page_submit_row %}` templatetag.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/cms/page/1/

Caught an exception while rendering: admin/page_submit_line.html

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8082/admin/cms/page/1/
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: Caught an exception while rendering: admin/page_submit_line.html
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py in render_node, line 81
```

Does anybody know also a good tutorial of django-cms?

Update: It seems that the installation of django-cms is not fully sucessful. The admin/page_submit_line.html template was missing. I've try to reinstall several time with similar result. A manual copy of the file fix the problem.

How can I be sure that the install has be done properly? I guess that some other files are missing. Is it safe to copy the missing files manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem comes from the django-cms installer. It was with RC2 and RC3 is out now.

Moreover, It is recommended to use easy_install for the installation

easy_instaling RC3 fixed the problem

Best

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `{% load %}` the template tag library at the top of your file.